# C++ returning collection by value

Tags: c++, collections

I want to make my collection immutable outside of my class.

from this:

```
public:    
    vector<int>& getValues(){
        return values;
    }
private: 
    vector <int>& values;
```

to this:

```
public:    
    vector<int> getValues(){
        return values;
    }
private: 
    vector <int>& values;
```

Will it work fine?

Comment: Did you try it? it's easy to do...

Comment: Are you sure you want a reference member?

Comment: The use of a reference as a member method is not *wrong* but it is not usual either, and it does not bode well with *"I want to make **my collection** immutable outside of **my class**"*. A reference there implies that the collection is not *owned* by the class. My first guess is that you don't want to store a reference, but without more code or a more complete description I am just leaving the comment out for you to think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work, but you would be better off returning a const reference:

```
const vector<int> & getValues() const {
    return values;
}
```

Also, storing a reference in a class is often (not always) a mistake. You probably want a value, or possibly a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it might have a negative impact on performance, if the collection is large, and the function is called often.  What's wrong with just returning a `vector<int> const&` (and declaring `getValues()` `const`)?

Also, I'm wondering about the fact that your member is a reference.  Members should rarely be references.

Answer (score 1):

```
public:    
    vector<int> getValues(){
        return values;
    }
private: 
    vector <int>& values;
```

Cannot possibly work as is, what is the reference to your vector actually referencing?  Unless you're not showing all code here, it's not gonna work.

Just have a `vector<int> values;` instead.

Comment: It may not be a good idea, but it works if the reference is initialized in the class' ctor.

Comment: He's obviously not showing all of the code, since a class with a reference member requires (always) a user defined constructor.  I'm skeptical about the reference member myself, but it has nothing to do with his actual question.

Comment: but what I'm saying is not technically wrong? I don't understand the downvote,

Comment: +1, I have had the same hunch: I believe that to be an error in the code, as the description seems to indicate that the class *owns* the collection, and that reference seems to imply the opposite, where *seems* means that there are ugly corner cases: `type() : values( *new vector<int> ) {}; ~type() { delete &values; }` but if that is being used... that is a problem in itself!

Comment: Thanks for discussion guys :)

Comment: @Tony the downvote is for "Cannot possibly work as is", which you don't know because the OP didn't posted the class' ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, but this is not necessarily what you want.

By doing this, your getValues method will make a copy of the vector.  This will take some time (depending on the size of the vector).

If you are sure that the vector is not frequently changed, why not return a const reference, like this:

```
const vector<int> &getValues() {return values;}
```

Answer (score 1):

return a `pair` of `const_iterators`, then the callee is abstracted from the underlying container too...

e.g.

```
   typedef std::vector<int> vector_type;
public:
   typedef std::pair<vector_type::const_iterator, vector_type::const_iterator> range;

   range getValues() const
   {
     return range(values.begin(), values.end());
   }
private:
   vector_type values;
```